# Cypress ignore some method from test duration calculation

Tags: cypress

I have the following case

```
// 1. interacting with the UI
// 2. performing a request to an Endpoint from the code using cy.request in order to get 
some information like dummy test data
// 3. interacting with the UI
```

I want cypress to ignore the 2. line from the test execution calculation, how could I achieve that? otherwiese I am getting inaccurate information about the test duration

Comment: Please show the test code you are using.

Comment: here is the code cy.request(). I need to ignore the execution time from the total test execution time. as simple as it is

Comment: Our dummy test data that we generate for our app is included in test execution. Any retries, using cypress-recurse, to the endpoint is part of our test execution time. Why are you looking to remove that?

Comment: so is are the requirements